# how can i add a transition effect in javascript for a push-side menu?

Tags: javascript, transition

How can i add a transition effect to the push-side menu? I tried using document.getElementById('content').style.transition = "left 1.5s";  but it doesnt work.  I woud apreciate some help.. I am a beginner in JS.

```js
//Javascript for showing the hidden menu
document.getElementById("showMenu").addEventListener("click", menuShow);
function menuShow ()
{
  document.getElementById('content').style.left = "20%";
  document.getElementById('content').style.opacity = "0.6";
  document.getElementById("content").style.transition = "opacity 2s";
};
//Javascript for hiding menu 
document.getElementById("hideMenu").addEventListener("click", menuHide);
function menuHide ()
{
  document.getElementById('content').style.left = "0";
  document.getElementById('content').style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("content").style.transition = "none";
 
};
```

```css
body
{
position: relative;
margin: 0;
}
/*Style for the fixed header and show menu button*/
#header
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#showMenu
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 0.2px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border: none;
  
}


#showMenu:hover 
{

  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}
/*Style for the content div*/
#content
{
 height: 768px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0B243B;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -7px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -7px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -7px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;     
}
p
{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: calibri;
  text-indent: 50px;
  
}

/*Style for the hidden menu div and hide menu button*/
#hiddenMenu
{

  height: 765px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  
 }
#hideMenu
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: -25px;
  font-family: calibri;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 80px;
  
  
}
#hideMenu:hover
{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;

 
}
/*Style for the hidden menu links*/
#hiddenMenu ul li 
{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
 
}
#hiddenMenu ul li:hover
{
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id=hiddenMenu> 
  <button id=hideMenu> &#8249</button>
  <ul>
    <li><a>About </a></li>
    <li><a> Home </a></li>
    <li><a> Gallery </a></li>
    <li><a> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id=content>
  <div id=header>
  <button id=showMenu> 
  &#9776
 </button> 
  </div>
  <p>
    Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. </p>

<p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  </p>
  
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use transaction property in css for hidden div

```
-webkit-transition: 2s; /* for Safari browser */
transition: 2s;
```

it will show the smooth movement for all changes (including Color change)

Answer (score 3):

Use animate.css

download animate.css from https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Add it to your project

```
<button  class="fadeOutFade"> &#8249</button>
  <ul>
    <li><a>About </a></li>
    <li><a> Home </a></li>
    <li><a> Gallery </a></li>
    <li><a> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id=content>
  <div id=header>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your approach (that you are adding 20% `left` css property to content) I suggest you want to slide menu from left and shift your page to the right ...

so all you need is:

```
#content {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 2s;
}
#content.menuShown {
  left: 20%;
}
```

and then javascript click handlers

```
document.getElementById("showMenu").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("content").classList.toggle("menuShown");
});

document.getElementById("hideMenu").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("content").classList.toggle("menuShown");
});
```

This way whenever you click menu button you toggle `.menuShown` class for `#content` element. And when content element has class `.menuShown` it is shifted to the right by 20% with transition.
Here's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/3dbepfxg/)

PS: there is a horizontal scrollbar visible when menu is shown, you can hide that using `body { overflow-x: hidden; }`. Or you could create a class from it and assign it to body only when menu is visible same way as `.menuShown` class is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help to you [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shankarrjg/6n6es2y2/1/)

```
  document.getElementById("content").style.transition = "opacity 2s, left .2s"
```